# Printing from PDF.js to Dot Matrix Printer

Tags: html, asp.net, pdf, printing, pdf.js

i'm trying to print an invoice from an ASP.NET application to an Epson LX 300+. The problem i have is that i cannot use traditional ReportViewer because printing icon only works on Internet Explorer, the users use Mozilla and Chrome.

We tried to render a HTML page for the invoice and print, but horizontally is reduced around a 50%.

So we are trying create a ReporViewer and export it to a PDF, then open it using PDF.js... the result is the same horizontally 50% less.

The page size is Statement. I'm attaching 2 images printed from the PDF.js

I've noticed if we vary the resolution of the printer, it's 90% horizontally, but also changes the vertically.

Your help would be really appreciated. Regads. Also We tried on Chrome but its really fuzzy.

[Printed from PDFjs on Mozilla 120x72dpi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni0DZ.jpg)

[Printed form PDFjs on Mozilla 120x144dpi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKFOq.jpg)

Comment: Would you be open to switch frameworks away from pdf.js ?

Comment: Yes, any solution will be great. @Jurion Thank you.

Comment: Well, on our end we’ve tried a lot of solutions for HTML to PDF generation. None worked. The closest was EvoPDF (Almost nice, almost. Except page breaks). So we’ve decided to do it “by hand” in back end. Take a look at ScryberPDF. It’s a library we’ve settled on. The main advantage: PDF is descriptive and have some kind (not full) CSS alternative.

Comment: Thank you @Jurion, will try. By the way, do you know any other option for printing the ReportViewer on Mozilla or Chrome? Regards.

Comment: Edit : here is an example of our PDF generation (Sorry it's in french) : http://pdfsr.com/pdf/project.pdf

Comment: Sorry, never used ReportViewer  in .Net :(